# The Power of Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, power-series, education

I am teaching a Calculus class and we are finishing up power/Taylor series this week.  The last section of the chapter is on applications, but the only ones listed there are approximating non-rational numbers like $\sqrt{1.02}$ and computing limits like $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$.  I would like to find better examples that may or may not have a quick physical application (I cannot assume they know any physics beyond what I can explain).  So, my question is, do any of you know some applications of Taylor series that I could spend maybe about half an hour to forty five minutes doing?  They needn't be physical applications, just interesting.  I have already done Euler's formula.  Also, we do not deal with any remainder theorems in this class.  Thanks.

Comment: "Integration" of things like $e^{x^2}$?

Comment: Solving differential equations.

Comment: Approximate a solution of $x^4 + y^4 = 2 x y$ near $(0,0)$ by $y = x^3/2 + x^{11}/32 + \ldots$.

Comment: Related: [Motivating infinite series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9524/motivating-infinite-series).

Comment: Taylor's theorem is used quite ingeniously in a proof of the central limit theorem (one doesn't need the whole series there, though. Just a few terms). Unfortunately, this probably doesn't fit into a 30-45 hour frame (unless the students have prior background in probability).

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I ended up doing Legendre polynomials from differential equations and $e$ is irrational.  I'm accepting the $e$ is irrational answer since I used it.  So, no offense to the other great answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not quite on the power of Taylor's series, but you could use the Taylor series for $f(x) = e^x$ to show that [$e$ is irrational.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational#Proof)

Answer (score 12):

Here is an interesting application of power series; unfortunately one would need to bother with the remainder to make it really interesting.

$$\arctan(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \,.$$

Plug in $x= \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ ($1$ would also work but one would need to explain why this formula also holds at the end point of the interval). We get:

$$\frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3^n2n+1} \,.$$

The right side is an alternating series which converges very fast, thus you can use it to calculate $\pi$ with 5-6 digits. And it is alternating, which means you could use the Alternating Series error estimate.

You can also do the same for the Taylor series of $e^x$.

Comment: Of course, some smart-ass will ask "how do you compute $\sqrt{3}$"? (This isn't hard - Newton's method converges quickly, for example, or one could find the series for $\sqrt{x}$ around $x=4$ - but it's worth thinking about beforehand.)

Comment: Nice example. One can alternately use $\pi/4=\arctan(1/2)+\arctan(1/3)$.

Comment: ...and in general, there's a whole family of [Machin-type formulae](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44595). The trick of course for speedy convergence is that the arguments of the arctangent should be as small (that is, near the expansion point) as possible.

Answer (score 8):

I presume the students would know how to sum (finite/infinite) geometric series. You can tell them that the infinite geometric series can be seen as the Taylor expansion of the function $\frac{1}{1-x}$:
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+ x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots.
$$
Integrating term by term (not always valid!), 
$$
-\ln (1-x) = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots,
$$
which is nothing but the Taylor expansion of the function $\ln(1+x)$. (Of course, you can also derive the Taylor expansion directly, if you prefer.) Finally, plugging in $x=-1$ (once again, not really valid!), we get the sum of the [alternating harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Alternating_harmonic_series): 
$$
\ln 2 = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots.
$$

There are many unjustified steps in the above derivation, but it gives a cool demonstration of power series and Taylor expansions.

Comment: Nice examples. To compute $\ln2$, one should definitely use $x=\frac12$ instead of $x=-1$. The unjustified steps disappear and, perhaps even more importantly, the series one obtains converges much more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that a certain function $f$ does not have any zero between $-1$ and $1$, for instance, by showing that $1/f$ is analytic with a radius of analyticity at least $1$ (and therefore finite).